# JPA PersistenceUnit vs Persistence

Tags: java, jpa

i have created JPA project and deployed on the glassfish v4 as the following:
 class -

```
package com.jpa.model;
class Lookup {
    private int id;
    private int label;

    .... [set/get methods]
}
```

META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <persistence version="2.1" ... ">
    <persistence-unit name="dbUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/MYSQL_DB</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.jpa.model.Lookup</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

EntityManagerUtil

```
public class EntityManagerUtil {
@PersistenceUnit(name="dbUnit")
protected static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public static void getAllLookups(){
    System.out.println("entityManagerFactory : "+entityManagerFactory);// always print null
    System.out.println(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dbUnit").createEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT L FROM Lookup L"));// always return correct values
}
}
```

--------------------------------------
When I try to call the @PersistenceUnit, always the return is null.
but when I try to use Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory, it always return correct values.

Please your advice & comment.

Answer (score 0):

The injection of dependencies only works on managed components like: EJB and Servlets. If you want to use injection of dependencies you must add EJB's annotations to your class `EntityManagerUtil`. I you do this then you must remove the `static` modifier of the variable  `entityManagerFactort` and from the method `getAllLookups`

If you are programming a Web Application you can use EJB 3.1 since you will deploy it on Glassfish v4.

Maybe this tutorial can help you to clear some ideas: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-ejb.html